# как в value вставить переменную vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Помогите пожалуйста, как в value вставить переменную
`<input id="link" type="text" value='{{id + $root.user.weapons}}' disabled/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на твой вопрос:

- **HTML**

```html
<input id="link" type="text" v-bind:value='value' disabled/>
```

- **Vue.JS**

```
var app = new Vue({ 
    el: '#link',
    data: {
        value: "Значение"
    }
});
```

Пояснения:

- Мы написали к атрибуту `v-bind:`, это привязка. Т.е в нашем **Vue.JS** файле есть переменная со ключом ***value*** и значением ***Значение***. Мы с нашим `v-bind:` обращаемся к **value (значение input)** и пишем название переменной, к которой мы отсылаемся.
- Так и получается `v-bind:value='value'` (v-bind: value(Атрибут input) = 'value(переменная)')

```js
var app = new Vue({ 
    el: '#link',
    data: {
        value: "Значение"
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<input id="link" type="text" v-bind:value='value' disabled/>
```

P.s.: я только что просмотрел Vue.JS и он мне очень понравился, буду его учить. Без тебя я бы не начал его изучать, Спасибо :3

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать директиву v-model для двунаправленного связывания данных с элементами форм input, textarea и select. Способ обновления элемента выбирается автоматически в зависимости от типа элемента. Хотя v-model и выглядит как нечто волшебное, в действительности это лишь синтаксический сахар для обновления данных в элементах ввода, с некоторыми поправками для исключительных случаев. [Больше информации тут](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

```js
const app = new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        inputValue: "some text"
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
<input id="link" type="text" v-model="inputValue" disabled/>
</div>
```